# Sequalize association fails (BelongsTo) NodeJs Sequalize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

Trying to work with sequalize association ( belongsTo and hasMany() ) but when i tries to query findAll with include the Model which was associated it fails by saying Models are not associated.

---

User Model

```
const {DATE, STRING, INTEGER} = require("sequelize");
const {USER} = require("../config/db.config");
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const User = sequelize.define("Users", {
        id: {
            primaryKey: true, type: INTEGER, required: true, autoIncrement: true
        }, phoneNumber: {
            type: STRING, required: true, unique: true
        }, firstname: {
            type: STRING, required: true
        }, middlename: {
            type: STRING, required: false
        }, region: {
            type: STRING, required: true
        }, district: {
            type: STRING, required: true
        }, street: {
            type: STRING, required: true
        }, lastname: {
            type: STRING, required: true,
        }, 'type': {
            type: STRING, required: true,
        }, email: {
            type: STRING, required: true, unique: true
        }, status: {
            type: Sequelize.ENUM("ACTIVE", "NOT-ACTIVE", "SUSPENDED"), defaultValue: "NOT-ACTIVE",
        }, createdAt: {
            type: DATE,
        }, updatedAt: {
            type: DATE,
        }
    });

    User.associate = function (models) {
        User.hasMany(models.Students, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user'});
    }

    return User;
};
```

---

Student Model

```
const {DATE, STRING, INTEGER} = require("sequelize");
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Student = sequelize.define("Students",
        {
            id: {
                primaryKey: true, type: STRING, required: true
            }, userId: {
                type: INTEGER, required: true,
            }, status: {
                type: Sequelize.ENUM("ACTIVE", "NOT-ACTIVE", "SUSPENDED"), defaultValue: "NOT-ACTIVE",
            },
            level: {
                type: STRING, required: true,
            }, createdAt: {
                type: DATE,
            }, updatedAt: {
                type: DATE,
            }
        });

    Student.associate = function (models) {
        Student.belongsTo(models.Users, {foreignKey: 'userId', as: 'user'})
        Student.belongsToMany(models.Classes, {through: 'StudentClass',})
    }
    return Student;
};
```

---

I have tried to query them by  using the bellow function but i got nothing

---

```
function getAllStudents() {
    Student.findAll({include: [{model: User, as: 'user', required: true}]}).then(value => {
        console.log(value)
        return value;
    }).catch(reason => {
        console.error(reason)
    })
}
```

But i get the following
[Result i get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eo9p4.png)

Comment: Obviously you didn't call models' `associate` methods for each model after their registration. Please show the code where you register models and associations

Comment: I did that  as ypu can see bellow
.forEach(file => {
        console.log(file)
        const model = require(path.join(__dirname, file))(sequelize, Sequelize.DataTypes);
        db[model.name] = model;
    });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
    if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db);
    }
});

Comment: If you did that then your models should have associations. check them in the `associations` prop of `Student` model right before executing `findAll`